# Virtualbox: cannot access tomcat 8080 in guest (ubuntu 15.05) from host (Windows 10)

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, virtualbox

I use Virtualbox with a bridged network between (Windows 10) and guest (Ubuntu Desktop 15.05).

Tomcat is running on port 8080 in the guest which has following ip address 192.168.1.10. I cannot access this instance from the host when typing  http://192.168.1.10:8080 in a browser. This is strange since I can access the postgreSQL instance which is running in the guest.

Has it something to do with the configuration of server.xml?

Comment: Check your server.xml - specifically the "Connector" entry.  There's an optional attribute named "address" which will cause Tomcat to bind to specific interface(s).  I don't have that attribute in my server.xml, so mine binds to all interfaces.  You can always run the netstat command to see what interfaces Tomcat is binding to.  Good luck!

Comment: I used `netstat -an | grep :8080` and I got a valid result. I also do not have any occurrence of `address` in the `server.xml` file. Here is the configuration of my connectors:

    `<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="8443" />

    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />`

Comment: With the netstat command, I saw that Tomcat was configured for ipv6. I hence added following into the catalina.sh file (none of the line works):

`# CATALINA_OPTS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
JAVA_OPTS= $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses`
Here's what I get when doing a netstat after that:

`daniel@europa:~$ netstat -an | grep :8080
tcp  0  0 127.0.0.1:34480 127.0.0.1:8080  ESTABLISHED
tcp6 0  0 :::8080 :::*  LISTEN 
tcp6 0  0 127.0.0.1:8080  127.0.0.1:34480 ESTABLISHED`

Comment: Even after changing to ipv4, it is still not reachable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The firewall port 8080 was not open. I used the following command to open it and it worked:

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=8080/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

For me, this code did the trick. It basically opens up the 8080 port to the public.

According to [ubuntu.com](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/firewall-cmd.1.html), firewall-cmd is the command line client of the firewalld daemon. It provides an interface to manage runtime and permanent configuration.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your code?